# How to change app version in ionic framework?

Tags: ionic-framework

How to change version code in Ionic framework and make sure it gets accepted by Play Store?

Play Store is not allowing to upload the generated apk, with version number 1000.

Comment: In config.xml: <widget android-packageName="com.package.app.android" android-versionCode="1000" id="com.package.app" version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">

Comment: @Sabari this may be the correct answer, please move your comment to the answers section.

Comment: @Ali please share your config.xml file

Comment: For the android, you have to edit your build.gradle file which will be available inside android folder inside your project.

In build.gradle file, you have to change versionCode and versionName

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In config.xml

```
<widget android-packageName="com.package.app.android" android-versionCode="1000" id="com.package.app" version="1.0" xmlns="w3.org/ns/widgets"; xmlns:cdv="cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

Comment: Hi, Can we set android version as version="0.0.10" ?? Please suggest.

Comment: For the android, you have to edit your build.gradle file which will be available inside android folder inside your project.

In build.gradle file, you have to change versionCode and versionName

Answer (score 7):

change these lines in config.xml. Build one at each time. Hope this will help

```
<!-- Android -->
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="0.0.1" android-versionCode="13" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
</widget>

<!-- iOS -->
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="0.0.1" ios-CFBundleVersion="0.1.3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
</widget>
```

Comment: What about those lines should I change? A little detail would be very helpful. I added android-versionCode to the line because it wasn't there before but that did do anything.

Comment: For the android, you have to edit your build.gradle file which will be available inside android folder inside your project.

In build.gradle file, you have to change versionCode and versionName

Answer (score 6):

For the android, you have to edit your `build.gradle` file which will be available inside android folder inside your project.

In build.gradle file, you have to change `versionCode` and `versionName`

see the example code below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.companyname.appname"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For ionic 4, there is no `android-versionCode` field.
So you should change the `version` in `widget` field (usually line 2) in the config.xml file.

For example:

```
<widget id="myapp.mycompany.com" version="0.0.3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

In this case, just change the version from 0.0.3 to 0.0.4 or to whatever number you want.

Comment: so we dont need to change android-versionCode ?

Comment: I think you don't need for ionic 4. But to be on the safe side just test it